# Unable to rotate image in windows store app

Tags: image, windows-8, microsoft-metro, image-rotation

I'm attempting to take a photo with my device camera, but images taken with the device held in "portrait" mode come out sideways.  I'd like to rotate them before saving them, but the solution that I keep coming across isn't working for me.

```
Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
imagePreview.Source = null;

await stream.WriteAsync(currentImage.AsBuffer());
stream.Seek(0);

BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(stream, decoder);
encoder.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise90Degrees;
encoder.IsThumbnailGenerated = false;
await encoder.FlushAsync();

//save the image
StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.SavedPictures;
StorageFile capturefile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("photo_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".bmp", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
string captureFileName = capturefile.Name;

//store stream in file
using (var fileStream = await capturefile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    try
    {
        //because of using statement stream will be closed automatically after copying finished
        await Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(stream, fileStream.AsOutputStream());
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

this produces the original image with no rotation applied to it.  I've looked at a lot of samples, and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?